# Div height animation direction issue from bottom

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm working on some text fill animation using an :after element on top of a text and animate the height of it to make the fill animation.

**It's working well with position absolute and top 0 on my :after element. But if I want to make the same animation of the height but in the oposite direction from bottom to top, I should change top 0 for a Bottom 0.**

That's where the issue appear, my :after element goes under my text block ?

Here is my code : https://codepen.io/1conu59/pen/zdVXOP

```css
.text {
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
   font-size: 12em;
   font-weight: 700;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: black;
   color: #fff;
 }

.text:after {
   transition: all 1s ease;
   content: attr(data-content);
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   color: black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 0%;
   overflow: hidden;
   *background-color: black;
   z-index: 1000;
 }

.text:hover:after {
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="text" data-content="Grandioso">

 Grandioso

</div>
```

Try changing top 0 to Bottom 0 for the .text:after and see the issue

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT : If you look closely there's also an issue with some kind of browser glitch I think. Its a 0.5 px line around the text when the animation is complete and it only appear when you animate from 0% to 100% not 100% to 0%. Do you have any idea how to fix that ? I use text shadow but the result is not great...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below snippet for your answer. I just changed your `height` property to animate from 100% to 0% and changed the default color and after color as after takes 100% height. Hope it helps.

```css
.text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color:#39A966;
}

.text:after {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  content: attr(data-content);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  *background-color: black;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.text:hover:after {
  height: 0%;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text" data-content="Grandioso">

  Grandioso

</div>
```

Comment: Haha you just switch the logic right ? Hover is now hidding the wrong color !  How did I miss that??? Sometime I feel so bad at this job man... Yes it helps so much i'm on this since two days now ! Thank you so much !

Comment: There's also a browser glitch that your way of doing it fixed ! But maybe you know something to fixe it on the other way. Because you're starting from 100% both text have exactly the same size and the fill animation is perfect. On the other way when you start from 0% you've got a weird 0.5px line arround the text of the color of the text in the background any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: I edited my first post for you to see more clealy the browser issue.

Comment: @GordonFreeman where do you find browser glitch? can you be specific?

Comment: If you look at this picture you'll see it ! I've the same issue on edge, firefox, and chrome. This is my first post I edited : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/37/3/1505324441-glitch.jpg

Comment: @GordonFreeman as per my understanding, surely there will be some glitches. Because you are using after content to override the existing text. So obviously it will not match 100%, because one is normal text and whatever overrides is some content(that need not be only text). To get better response you should post it in a separate question, so people can answer in better way.